# pip install qiskit errors

Tags: python, linux, qiskit

So I'm trying to get qiskit to work on my system (arch linux) but I'm having trouble installing qiskit, specifically qiskit-aer. I've seen several other posts with similar issues suggesting that I downgrade python. To do this I'm using pyenv running python 3.8.7 so if I run `python -V` i get the output `python 3.8.7`. Still when i try to pip install qiskit i get this gigantic error that i'll leave below:

I noticed that even running pyenv if i do `pip --version` i get the output `pip 21.3.1 from /home/gustavo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)`  i don't know if that has anything to do with it. Any help getting this thing to work is much appreciated.

`````
   command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-yvnffenf
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/
  Complete output (199 lines):
  /home/gustavo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
    warnings.warn(


  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_cmake_test_compile/build
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator - success
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Configuring Project
    Working directory:
      /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build
    Command:
      /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/.eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/bin/cmake /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29 -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-install -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.10.1 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.10 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/libpython3.10.so -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:STRING=10.9 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release

  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Performing Test flag_supported
  -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
  -- Performing Test flag_supported
  -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
  -- Performing Test flag_supported
  -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
  -- Performing Test flag_supported
  -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
  -- Performing Test flag_supported
  -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
  -- Performing Test flag_supported
  -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
  -- Performing Test flag_supported
  -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
  -- Performing Test flag_supported
  -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
  -- Performing Test flag_supported
  -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
  -- Performing Test flag_supported
  -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
  -- Performing Test flag_supported
  -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
  -- Conan: Automatic detection of conan settings from cmake
  -- Conan: Settings= -s;build_type=Release;-s;compiler=gcc;-s;compiler.version=11;-s;compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
  -- Conan: checking conan executable
  -- Conan: Found program /usr/bin/conan
  -- Conan: Version found Conan version 1.43.0

  -- Conan executing: /usr/bin/conan install . -s build_type=Release -s compiler=gcc -s compiler.version=11 -s compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 -e=CONAN_CMAKE_PROGRAM=/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/.eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/bin/cmake -g=cmake --build=missing
  Configuration:
  [settings]
  arch=x86_64
  arch_build=x86_64
  build_type=Release
  compiler=gcc
  compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
  compiler.version=11
  os=Linux
  os_build=Linux
  [options]
  [build_requires]
  [env]
  CONAN_CMAKE_PROGRAM=/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/.eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/bin/cmake
  conanfile.txt: Installing package
  Requirements
      fmt/6.2.1 from 'conancenter' - Cache
      muparserx/4.0.8 from 'conancenter' - Cache
      nlohmann_json/3.1.1 from 'conancenter' - Cache
      spdlog/1.5.0 from 'conancenter' - Cache
  Packages
      fmt/6.2.1:6557f18ca99c0b6a233f43db00e30efaa525e27e - Cache
      muparserx/4.0.8:6557f18ca99c0b6a233f43db00e30efaa525e27e - Cache
      nlohmann_json/3.1.1:5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9 - Cache
      spdlog/1.5.0:bf273214613ae9cd4f65a4be0b5f493fe5d66e2b - Cache

  Installing (downloading, building) binaries...
  fmt/6.2.1: Already installed!
  muparserx/4.0.8: Already installed!
  nlohmann_json/3.1.1: Already installed!
  spdlog/1.5.0: Already installed!
  conanfile.txt: Generator cmake created conanbuildinfo.cmake
  conanfile.txt: Generator txt created conanbuildinfo.txt
  conanfile.txt: Aggregating env generators
  conanfile.txt: Generated conaninfo.txt
  conanfile.txt: Generated graphinfo
  -- Conan: Loading conanbuildinfo.cmake
  -- Conan: Adjusting output directories
  -- Conan: Using cmake targets configuration
  -- Library spdlog found /home/gustavo/.conan/data/spdlog/1.5.0/_/_/package/bf273214613ae9cd4f65a4be0b5f493fe5d66e2b/lib/libspdlog.a
  -- Library muparserx found /home/gustavo/.conan/data/muparserx/4.0.8/_/_/package/6557f18ca99c0b6a233f43db00e30efaa525e27e/lib/libmuparserx.a
  -- Library fmt found /home/gustavo/.conan/data/fmt/6.2.1/_/_/package/6557f18ca99c0b6a233f43db00e30efaa525e27e/lib/libfmt.a
  -- Conan: Adjusting language standard
  -- Current conanbuildinfo.cmake directory: /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build
  -- Conan: Compiler GCC>=5, checking major version 11
  -- Conan: Checking correct version: 11
  -- Looking for OpenMP support...
  -- OpenMP found!
  -- OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS = -fopenmp
  -- OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS =
  -- Looking for pthread.h
  -- Looking for pthread.h - found
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
  -- Found Threads: TRUE
  -- Looking for OpenBLAS library...
  -- OpenBLAS not found. Looking for any other BLAS & Lapack libraries...
  -- Looking for sgemm_
  -- Looking for sgemm_ - not found
  CMake Error at .eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
    Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    .eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    .eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:1337 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
    CMakeLists.txt:222 (find_package)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 586, in setup
      env = cmkr.configure(cmake_args,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 237, in configure
      raise SKBuildError(

  An error occurred while configuring with CMake.
    Command:
      /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/.eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/bin/cmake /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29 -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-install -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.10.1 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.10 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/libpython3.10.so -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:STRING=10.9 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
    Source directory:
      /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29
    Working directory:
      /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build
  Please see CMake's output for more information.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for qiskit-aer
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-zdzqufj0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/gustavo/.local/include/python3.10/qiskit-aer
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/
    Complete output (201 lines):
    /home/gustavo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    /home/gustavo/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
      warnings.warn(


    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Trying "Ninja" generator
    --------------------------------
    ---------------------------
    ----------------------
    -----------------
    ------------
    -------
    --
    Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    --
    -------
    ------------
    -----------------
    ----------------------
    ---------------------------
    --------------------------------
    -- Trying "Ninja" generator - failure
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator
    --------------------------------
    ---------------------------
    ----------------------
    -----------------
    ------------
    -------
    --
    Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    -- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_cmake_test_compile/build
    --
    -------
    ------------
    -----------------
    ----------------------
    ---------------------------
    --------------------------------
    -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator - success
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Configuring Project
      Working directory:
        /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build
      Command:
        /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/.eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/bin/cmake /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29 -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-install -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.10.1 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.10 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/libpython3.10.so -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:STRING=10.9 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release

    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
    -- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Performing Test flag_supported
    -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
    -- Performing Test flag_supported
    -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
    -- Performing Test flag_supported
    -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
    -- Performing Test flag_supported
    -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
    -- Performing Test flag_supported
    -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
    -- Performing Test flag_supported
    -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
    -- Performing Test flag_supported
    -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
    -- Performing Test flag_supported
    -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
    -- Performing Test flag_supported
    -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
    -- Performing Test flag_supported
    -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
    -- Performing Test flag_supported
    -- Performing Test flag_supported - Success
    -- Conan: Automatic detection of conan settings from cmake
    -- Conan: Settings= -s;build_type=Release;-s;compiler=gcc;-s;compiler.version=11;-s;compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
    -- Conan: checking conan executable
    -- Conan: Found program /usr/bin/conan
    -- Conan: Version found Conan version 1.43.0

    -- Conan executing: /usr/bin/conan install . -s build_type=Release -s compiler=gcc -s compiler.version=11 -s compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 -e=CONAN_CMAKE_PROGRAM=/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/.eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/bin/cmake -g=cmake --build=missing
    Configuration:
    [settings]
    arch=x86_64
    arch_build=x86_64
    build_type=Release
    compiler=gcc
    compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
    compiler.version=11
    os=Linux
    os_build=Linux
    [options]
    [build_requires]
    [env]
    CONAN_CMAKE_PROGRAM=/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/.eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/bin/cmake
    conanfile.txt: Installing package
    Requirements
        fmt/6.2.1 from 'conancenter' - Cache
        muparserx/4.0.8 from 'conancenter' - Cache
        nlohmann_json/3.1.1 from 'conancenter' - Cache
        spdlog/1.5.0 from 'conancenter' - Cache
    Packages
        fmt/6.2.1:6557f18ca99c0b6a233f43db00e30efaa525e27e - Cache
        muparserx/4.0.8:6557f18ca99c0b6a233f43db00e30efaa525e27e - Cache
        nlohmann_json/3.1.1:5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9 - Cache
        spdlog/1.5.0:bf273214613ae9cd4f65a4be0b5f493fe5d66e2b - Cache

    Installing (downloading, building) binaries...
    fmt/6.2.1: Already installed!
    muparserx/4.0.8: Already installed!
    nlohmann_json/3.1.1: Already installed!
    spdlog/1.5.0: Already installed!
    conanfile.txt: Generator cmake created conanbuildinfo.cmake
    conanfile.txt: Generator txt created conanbuildinfo.txt
    conanfile.txt: Aggregating env generators
    conanfile.txt: Generated conaninfo.txt
    conanfile.txt: Generated graphinfo
    -- Conan: Loading conanbuildinfo.cmake
    -- Conan: Adjusting output directories
    -- Conan: Using cmake targets configuration
    -- Library spdlog found /home/gustavo/.conan/data/spdlog/1.5.0/_/_/package/bf273214613ae9cd4f65a4be0b5f493fe5d66e2b/lib/libspdlog.a
    -- Library muparserx found /home/gustavo/.conan/data/muparserx/4.0.8/_/_/package/6557f18ca99c0b6a233f43db00e30efaa525e27e/lib/libmuparserx.a
    -- Library fmt found /home/gustavo/.conan/data/fmt/6.2.1/_/_/package/6557f18ca99c0b6a233f43db00e30efaa525e27e/lib/libfmt.a
    -- Conan: Adjusting language standard
    -- Current conanbuildinfo.cmake directory: /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build
    -- Conan: Compiler GCC>=5, checking major version 11
    -- Conan: Checking correct version: 11
    -- Looking for OpenMP support...
    -- OpenMP found!
    -- OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS = -fopenmp
    -- OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS =
    -- Looking for pthread.h
    -- Looking for pthread.h - found
    -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
    -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
    -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
    -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
    -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
    -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
    -- Found Threads: TRUE
    -- Looking for OpenBLAS library...
    -- OpenBLAS not found. Looking for any other BLAS & Lapack libraries...
    -- Looking for sgemm_
    -- Looking for sgemm_ - not found
    CMake Error at .eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
      Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      .eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
      .eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:1337 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
      CMakeLists.txt:222 (find_package)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 586, in setup
        env = cmkr.configure(cmake_args,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 237, in configure
        raise SKBuildError(

    An error occurred while configuring with CMake.
      Command:
        /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/.eggs/cmake-3.22.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/cmake/data/bin/cmake /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29 -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-install -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.10.1 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.10 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/libpython3.10.so -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET:STRING=10.9 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
      Source directory:
        /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29
      Working directory:
        /tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build
    Please see CMake's output for more information.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hdx4vhk7/qiskit-aer_a40dd1ec77a24f92ad7ab25442a2ee29/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-zdzqufj0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/gustavo/.local/include/python3.10/qiskit-aer Check the logs for full command output.````
`````

Comment: It seems that qiskit is requiring BLAS matrix library, but it is not listed as a Conan dependency, maybe it is vendored in qiskit, or assumed to be in the system because there was not a BLAS package in ConanCenter some time ago? (it seems there is at least openBLAS now: https://conan.io/center/openblas)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i installed openblas and now it installed just fine apparently, but i'm now having trouble importing qiskit-aer, it prompts me to pip install qiskit-aer, but that is already installed. Trying to import it gives me the error `MissingOptionalLibrary`. Any leads?

Comment: I managed to figure it out, i switched the openblas package for openblas-lapack package and now it works just fine, I'll write an answer and close this post, thanks again @drodri much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the suggestions by [@drodri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3215383/drodri) in the comments of the original post I managed to get a solution. Basically I was missing a the `openblas` dependency. With that i managed to get qiskit installed, although qiskit-aer was not working when I tried to import it. To fix that i just needed to install `openblas-lapack` package (that required me to uninstall openblas because of package conflicts) and now everything's working correctly. Thanks to [@drodri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3215383/drodri) once again